# Using AlwasyOn Failover Cluster Instance in conjunction of Peer to Peer Transactional Replicaiton

Tags: failovercluster, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, p2p, alwayson

We are deploying two physical sites each with writable/readable access to its local SQL server. Each site has site redundancy and also cross site synchronization is required. My thought is to use the AlwaysOn Failover Cluster instance to achieve intra-site redundancy and Peer to Peer Transactional Replication to achieve cross site synchronization. In case of fail over within a site, will the Peer to Peer Transactional Replication be preserved? I assume it would since the entire SQL server instance is failed over. I cannot seem to find articles on the internet mentioning the combined use of these two technologies. Has anyone designed such a system and is it feasible to do so?

Thank you for your advice and help.

Comment: What’s the bandwidth & latency between your sites?

Comment: @BaronSamedi1958 the bandwidth between two sites is 10Mbps which is shared with other activities.

Comment: You won't be able to replicate anything in a sync manner with only 10 Mbps shared ;( FCI needs shared storage, and no shared storage can sync over 10 Mbps both ways.

Comment: @BaronSamedi1958 hmm. How about using AlwaysOn High Availability group with p2p transactional replication?